# alter session NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR inside the packages / stored procedures

Tags: oracle, session, plsql, oracle10g, session-variables

our application works on oracle 10g database and we are planning to migrate it to exadata now.
For that sake we have to follow some compliance which would accepted by exadata.
One of which is adding the statement to each and every existing package/procedure / function at beginning of the definition

```
alter session set NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS='CHAR'
```

I just want to check, may altering the session to change this session variable impact the code functionality?
what are things we have to keep in mind while adding this statement to all the the objects?

Any leads would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

REVISION:

I am revising my answer because of recommendations from another respected Oracle employee expert (Sergiusz Wolicki), and the fact that the documentation was revised on this parameter to warn against setting it to CHAR as an initialization parameter, and the fact that the warning is still there for 12.1

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch3globenv.htm#NLSPG234

> Caution: Oracle strongly recommends that you do NOT set the
>   NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter to CHAR in the instance or server
>   parameter file. This may cause many existing installation scripts to
>   unexpectedly create columns with character length semantics, resulting
>   in run-time errors, including buffer overflows.

CAVEAT:
IF the DDL script is written without explicit semantics, then setting the parameter doesn't impact it, however, it apparently isn't something that was safely updated across the board within the Oracle product scripts.

With well-written code, it certainly wont impact the "code functionality", it is a setting that simply impacts new field widths. The crux here seems to be how comfortable you are that you can guarantee this.

However, if Oracle warns against it, they have experience and evidence for doing so. A legacy app or tool that isn't aware of length semantics may be impacted.

The Oracle default is traditionally `BYTE` because of backwards compatibility, but for a new database with **no legacy stuff**, there is no risk to changing it, and it doesn't impact the internal data dictionary because those are locked to `BYTE` semantics regardless of the database setting for NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS.

Comment: I've thought about changing this setting before but got scared off by the warning on [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams152.htm#REFRN10124).  I'm not sure if it's a real warning or something that hasn't been updated in 20 years.

Comment: Here is what I've referring to lately. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:29518831139714 - I had recently changed one of my databases to CHAR semantics permanently, 11.2,  to test scenarios for my database products, and no ill effects. That said, I think it is worth further consideration. Usually if there is a concern, Tom Kyte will bring it up. In that thread, he does not.

Comment: See I am not the only one that was misled by Tom. https://community.oracle.com/thread/2194933 - After reading that, and noting that the warning in the 11.2 docs was patched in later (after I read it years ago), I reverse my stance. My opinion of Oracle is that they are extremely careful about compatibility and security, so I trusted both the docs and Tom Kyte on this. But reading Sergiusz Wolicki (Oracle)'s warning that is now in the docs, this was a mistake.

Comment: @JonHeller - I revised my answer, thanks for calling this to my attention. The warning is still in 12.1 docs. I'd been to that doc page many times over the years, but apparently not since 2013 when a SR was filed to revise it. You saved me future embarrassment. I expect at some point, we will see it become standard, by Oracle release 14 perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the original question is about altering session value of NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS. This case is not covered by the warning in the docs. If you want to create objects with character length semantics in the session using older scripts, then this ALTER SESSION is perfectly fine.

The doc warning is specifically against setting the parameter in init.ora, because such setting will affect all sessions that do not set the parameter explicitly (through ALTER SESSION or environment variable). If you are not careful, you can run various legacy scripts, including Oracle's, third-party or your home-grown ones and create objects with wrong semantics, not expected by the owning application. Character semantics instead of byte semantics will not cause issues for many applications, and will not be detected as a problem, but may cause issues, including security issues in some cases. Therefore, Oracle recommends that you set the length semantics explicitly in your scripts instead of relying on a database-wide setting that breaks compatibility of old stuff.

If you insist on setting NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS in init.ora, you must remember to reset it or override it for all scripts expecting BYTE semantics. This may be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this update worked.
You need to restart the Oracle server.
update sys.props$ set NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = CHAR